# How do I filter the columns of a table visualization?

Tags: powerbi

Using the following sales table as an example which records the volume of products sold by each salesperson per year:

[image: Sample Sales Table]

I created a stacked column visualization showing products sold per year:

[image]

What I want to happen when I click on "Cakes" is a report to show:

```
Resource, Year, Cakes
Rajeev Argwal, 2018, 678
Rajeev Argwal, 2019, 876
Rajeev Argwal, 2020, 2
```

When I select a specific item in the stacked column such as "2019 Soup" I want the report to show:

```
Resource, Year, Soup
Jane Smith, 2019, 800
Rajeev Argwal, 2019, 225
```

What is the right approach to do this?  Effectively filtering the table visualization to show only the relevant rows and columns.

Comment: You need to unpivot your table for products.

Comment: TIL the word unpivot.  Thanks RADO, exactly the prompt I needed.  Happy to mark this as the answer if you submit it as such.